# how to get name of dynamically generated method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

**I have achieved url as follows**

> myapp.com/profile/username1
>
> myapp.com/profile/username2
>
> myapp.com/profile/username3

**my routes.php file contains following line of code**

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'profile/user_profile/$profile_method';
```

**my `profile` controller contains this code**

```
    public function user_profile($profile_method)
    {
        echo $profile_method;
    }
```

all is well but the problem is i want to return username to process further, this method returns the parameter name instead of username. please tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Just tip You have no `/` after username myapp.com/profile/username/1

Try

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'profile/user_profile/$1';
$route['profile/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'profile/user_profile/$1/$2';
```

Instead of

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'profile/user_profile/$profile_method';
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Then

```
public function user_profile($profile_method = '', $id = '')
{
    echo $profile_method . ' <br/> ' . $id;
}
```

Make sure you have named your controllers and other files correct where only the first letter of class and file name is upper case Profile.php

You may need to have a htaccess in main directory to remove index.php from url also.

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

---

From [Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson) comment

CI is using regular expressions to replace the dynamic url variable, which means that $1 = the first match, $2 = the second match etc. The $-part isn't am ordinary php-variable, so you can't name it to what you want.

---

Comment: it works fine. But still i want to know how it works and changing parameter name in routes why affected on related controller

Comment: @SarjilShaikh - CI's router is using regular expressions to replace the dynamic url variable, which means that `$1` = the first match, `$2` = the second match etc. The `$`-part isn't an ordinary php-variable, so you can't name it to what you want.